Finding a power series and domain of convergence of $ln(\frac{1-x}{1+x^2})$
As said in the title, I need to find the power series of $ln(\frac{1-x}{1+x^2})$ as well as it's domain of convergence.
I was able to do the following:
rewrite $\ln(\frac{1-x}{1+x^2}) = \ln(1-x) - \ln(1+x^2)$, and then use the power series representation $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ to find out the power series for each of the terms:
$$\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(-x)^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty-\frac{x^n}{n}$$
$$\ln(1+x^2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(x^2)^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}$$
Now combining them: $$\ln(1-x) - \ln(1+x^2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty-\frac{x^n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty-\frac{x^n}{n}+(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}$$
And i'm not sure how to continue from here. I.e I don't know how to bring this into the form of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ in order to use theorems such as Cauchy-Hadamard's theorem to find the radius of convergence.
Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Your formula for $a_n$ will depend on whether $n$ is odd or even. If $n$ is odd,  only the first power series will have a term of degree $n$. If $n$ is even, both series will have terms of degree $n$, but the coefficient contributed by $\ln(1+x^2)$ will depend on $n/2$.

The radius of convergence of each series is equal $1.$ By considering only the  odd power terms the radius of convergence is at most $1.$  Hence the radius of convergence of the difference is equal $1.$

If you know that the radius of convergence (ROC) of $x \mapsto \log (1+x)$ is $R=1$, then you don't need to use Cauchy Hadamard.
In general, for any power series, if $R$ is the ROC, then the series converges absolutely for $|x|<R$ and diverges for $|x|>R$. In particular, if the series converges at any $x$ then $R \ge |x|$. Similarly, if the series diverges at $x$, then we must have $|x|\ge R$.
Note that $\lim_{x \uparrow 1} \log { 1-x \over 1+x^2} = \infty$, hence the ROC must be $\le 1$.
For $|x|< 1$, we have $\log { 1-x \over 1+x^2} = \log ( 1-x ) - \log (1+x^2)$. Note that the ROC of $x \mapsto \log (1-x)$ is one and since $R^2=R$, that the ROC of $x \mapsto \log (1 + x^2)$ is one. Hence, for $|x|<1$, we see that the power series is given by the sum of the constituent series, and hence the ROC must be $\ge 1$.
